# varying environment variables to different deploys (AzureDevOps/NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, git, azure-devops, continuous-integration, environment-variables

I'm trying to get in place a CI/CD pipeline using azureDevOps.

It is the first time for me trying something like that; the idea is to have my node/express API to be developed on my machine (DEV env). As soon as I have a push on the master branch on Azure Repos, the CI pipeline will start. This pipeline at the moment does the following:

- Install Node v12.x
- Install npm modules
- Run a npm command named test:ci
- Publish in Artifacts test coverage and test results
- Run a npm command named compile that compiles my typescript code in the build/ folder

This is where I am now, I would love to create a Docker container with my built app and then do something with it on my prod server. Here it comes my question, I have a .env file in my DEV env and that file is not pushed with git. How do I setup in the build process a new .env file? Is there a super smart way to do so, or have I just to setup a node script that will create the .env file at build time based on a .env.example file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Secure files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops) to easily include the .env file in your build pipeline. You can refer to below steps.

1, upload your .env file to azure devops as secure file.

In your Project go to **Library** under **Pipelines** --> Click **Secure files** --> Click **+ Secure file** to upload .env file to azure devops.

[image]

Click the **3dots** and choose **Edit**, Enble **Authorize for use in all pipelines**

[image]

2, Use .env file in azure devops pipeline. You need use [Download Secure File task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops)

Once .env file is downloaded, you can use the name value that is set on the task (or "Reference name" in the classic editor) to reference the path to the .env file on the agent machine. For example, if the task is given the name myEnvFile, its path can be referenced in the pipeline as `$(myEnvFile.secureFilePath)`(it is downloaded to the $(Agent.TempDirectory)).

```
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: myEnvFile
  displayName: 'Download .env file'
  inputs:
    secureFile: '.env'
```

3, you can add a copy file task to copy the downloaded .env file to your source code folder(eg. `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`)

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: $(Agent.TempDirectory)
      Contents: '**\.env'
      TargetFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

Then the .env file will be available at the build runtime.
Hope above helps!